# I need help in figuring out the code error after applying anti_join

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

TABLE_1

```
x   y   z   amount  absolute amount
121 abc def 500 700
131 fgh xyz -800    800
121 abc xyz 900 900
131 fgh ijk 800 800
141 obc pqr 500 500
151 mbr pqr -500    500
141 obc pqr -500    500
151 mbr pqr 900 900
```

applying the following code, i get the desired output-

```
c=df.groupby(['x','y'])['amount'].transform('sum')
df[c.ne(0) & c.abs().ne(df.absolute_amount)]
```

TABLE_2

```
x   y   z   amount  absolute amount
121 abc def 500 700
121 abc xyz 900 900
151 mbr pqr -500    500
151 mbr pqr 900 900
```

But when i further want a table in which Return rows in TABLE_1 which are not present in TABLE_2 and generate a new table (TABLE_3)

And apply some group by and filters to TABLE_3-

```
lis = anti_join_all_cols(TABLE_1, TABLE_2) 

dd = lis.groupby(['x','y'])['amount'].transform('sum')
TABLE_3 = lis[c.ne(0) & c.abs().ne(df.Absolute Amount)]
```

the following warning pops up-

```
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

Answer (score 0):

'c' is a series generated by operation on dataframe df & it has a different index than dataframe 'lis' for Table_3, you are trying to put these 2 together, hence the error. if the last lise is `Table_3=lis[dd.ne(0) & dd.abs().ne(lis.absolute_amount)]`, the nyou will not get this error (however, you will get an empty dataframe).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, I am getting an empty dataframe. How can run the conditions on lis?

Comment: you are getting an empty dataframe because series 'dd' has only zeroes (print dd & check). This is how the data is.